# ¿Cómo hago que funcione un <button type="submit"> dentro de una tabla con method="post" y action="cart.php"

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, datatables, metodos

Tengo una tabla con varios datos traídos desde mySQL. Necesito que el dato "coste_kg" sea agregado a un carrito de compras para posteriormente sumar todos los precios. Anteriormente había logrado que el botón que envía los datos al carrito funcionara dentro de un formulario. Pero quiero que sea posible realizar este proceso dentro de una tabla. En la tabla el botón no realiza la acción que debería.

Este es el código del formulario donde todo funcionaba correctamente:

```html
        <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row" style="justify-content: center;">

        <div class="card m-4" style="width: 18rem;">
                <form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" action="cart.php">
                <input name="coste_kg" type="hidden" id="coste_kg" value="<?php echo $fila['coste_kg']; ?>" />
                <input name="descripcion" type="hidden" id="descripcion" value="<?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?>" />
                <input name="cantidad" type="hidden" id="cantidad" value="1" class="pl-2" />
                <img src="img/art.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $fila['codigo']; ?></h5>
                                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?> - Precio <?php echo $fila['coste_kg']; ?></p>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Añadir al carrito</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
        </div>
```

Todo eso, lo que hice fue pasarlo a esta tabla:

```html
          <table id="formulario" name="formulario" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%"
            method="post" action="cart.php">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Linea</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Coste/Kg</th>
                <th>Agregar</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $fila['codigo']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila['linea']; ?></td>
                <td name="descripcion" id="descripcion" value="<?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?>">
                 <?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?>
                </td>
                <td name="coste_kg" id="coste_kg" value="<?php echo $fila['coste_kg']; ?>">
                <?php echo $fila['coste_kg']; ?>
                </td>
                <td> <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart">
                </i> Añadir</button>
                </td>
                <td name="cantidad" type="hidden" id="cantidad" value="1" class="pl-2"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

El botón tiene las mismas propiedades que el del formulario, igual ambos tienen el mismo method y action. ¿Cúal podría ser el problema?

Por ultimo, les dejo la pagina a la que hago referencia en el action="cart.php"

```html
<?php session_start(); 
//Here starts the cart


$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "alcon");
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM materia_prima ";
$dato = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL);

if ($dato->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($dato)) {



        if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {
            $carrito_mio = $_SESSION['carrito'];
            if (isset($_POST['descripcion'])) {
                $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
                $coste_kg = $_POST['coste_kg'];
                $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
                $num = 0;
                $carrito_mio[] = array("descripcion" => $descripcion, "coste_kg" => $coste_kg, "cantidad" => $cantidad);
            }
        } else {
            $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
            $coste_kg = $_POST['coste_kg'];
            $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
            $carrito_mio[] = array("descripcion" => $descripcion, "coste_kg" => $coste_kg, "cantidad" => $cantidad);
        }

    }
}
$_SESSION['carrito']=$carrito_mio;

//Here finishes the cart


header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
?>
```

Comment: La acción de "submit" funciona sólo para formularios. Tendrán que manejar la petición con Javascript. O meter toda la tabla en un formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Cada etiqueta en HTML tiene una utilidad, un sentido, y solo admite unas propiedades concretas. No deberías reemplazar la etiqueta `form` por una etiqueta `table`, ni deberías cambiar los `<input type="hidden">` por `<td>`. Lo que puedes hacer es meter la tabla dentro de un formulario e incluir los campos dentro de las celdas:

```
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" action="cart.php">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Linea</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Coste/Kg</th>
                <th>Agregar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fila['codigo']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['linea']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" value="<?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?>"
                    <?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="coste_kg" id="coste_kg" value="<?php echo $fila['coste_kg']; ?>"
                    <?php echo $fila['coste_kg']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"> </i> Añadir</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```